# jQuery selector Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Still new on programming, I'm trying to send data on my python script.
Dont have idea what's the error is all about

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("tags").keyup(function({
    var search = $("tags").val()
    $.post("/search",{
      suggestion: search
    },function(data,status){
      $('tags').html(data)
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the **error**:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier* on line 3 (var search = $("tags").val())

Comment: `function({` should be `function(){` on line 2

Comment: You're missing a `)` between `function(` and `{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close parenthesis

```
$("tags").keyup(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `id` or `class` signs in :

```
$("tags").val())
```

Should be :

```
$(".tags").val());
//Or
$("#tags").val());
```

Else your script will try to select the HTML tags `<tags>`.

**NOTE :** You're missing a close-parentheses `)` in :

```
$("tags").keyup(function(){
_________________________^
```

Comment: This won't cause a syntax error...

Comment: And the edit is a typo and therefor a reason for closure